# Modify master config in YugaByteDb

Tags: yugabytedb

I'm new in using yugabyte-db and i tried to use 3 local cluster by running `./bin/yb-clt --rf 3 create` it work well but ysql is disabled by default (`--enable_ysql=false`) is there any way to change masters configuration without running new yb-master process?

Answer (score 0):

Changing yb-master config is done using the `change-master-config` subcommand on `yb-admin` cli. Arguments will depend on the type of config. Direct link to the command with arguments:

https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#change-master-config

`--enable_ysql=false` is default only in pre-2.0.3 versions. All versions after it have it enabled by default.

And changing it in runtime is not possible. Only on startup.

Comment: Can you show it with an example on --enable_ysql?Because I tried this subcommand but didn`t work.

Comment: @AliZeinali that's not changable at runtime but only on startup